# Auto wrap all the links and buttons with div using HOC

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a `HOC` with ability to loop through all the inside `components` and wrap all the `links` and `buttons` with a `div` that will generate a unique `key` on each of them.

Obviously generating a `key` isn't an issue, but I have no clue of how to recursively(I don't see other option) go through all the children `components` including possible `routes`, defined by the `react router` etc.

Needless to say I don't want to make any manual changes to the inner `components`(that's the whole point here).

And also, I want to build the unique `keys` somehow only in development phase, so in the production it will show, but not going to be generated each time. Somehow as `SCSS's modules` do it with class names.

I'm really not sure if this is possible to achieve through `react` itself, so will appreciate any constructive feedback you got.

Just to make things a bit more clearly for what I'm trying to achieve, here's some code:

```
function App() {
  <Provider>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/one" component={ComponentOne}></Route>
      <Route path="/two" component={ComponentTwo}></Route>
      <Route path="/three" component={ComponentThree}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Provider>
}

const ComponentOne = () => {
  // ...
  // Possible other routes
  <ComponentOneOne />
  <ComponentOneTwo />
  // ...
}

const ComponentOneOne = () => {
  // ...
  // Possible other routes
  <ComponentOneOneOne />
  <ComponentOneOneTwo />
  // ...
}
```